# jquery-rails breaks kaminari?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ujs, kaminari

I updated my Rails 3.0.7 application to use kaminari 0.12.4 (up from 0.10.4) for pagination and jquery-rails 1.0.9 and it seemed to break pagination.  I've regenerated the kaminari views since they are different but for some reason ajax isn't working.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

is included.  Which produces this in the browser:

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1306353646" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js?1306368501" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1306381513" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1290034766" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In my view I have:
    <%= paginate @users, :remote => true %>

Which yields the following error:

> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing
>   template users/show with
>   {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder,
>   :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:js,
>   "application/ecmascript",
>   "application/x-ecmascript", "*/*"],
>   :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths
>   "/home/epipheus/CodeWarehouse/praypeer/app/views",
>   "/home/epipheus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/kaminari-0.12.4/app/views"):

the following non-ajax version works just fine of course:

```
<%= paginate @users, :remote => false %>
```

So it seems like I have something wrong with jquery ujs?  Please help me.

Comment: Seems with jquery you need to add index.js.html like this: $('#users').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@users) %>');
$('.app-table-pager').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@users, :remote => true).to_s) %>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that for jquery kaminari needs you to insert the following to say show.js.erb for example:

```
$('#microposts').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@microposts) %>');
$('.app-table-pager').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@microposts, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

If you don't switch to jquery-rails/ujs -- out of the box, it doesn't seem you need this.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had problems with jquery-rails after update. I updated the gem via bundler, but it was not quite compatible with an existing jquery-rails files. After I ran "rails generate jquery:install" command, I did not see any more errors.

Comment: I even removed all javascript files and did a rails g jquery:install --ui

Comment: Oh, sorry, this was not a config but a set of js files. If jquery:install did not help, let's see if someone else can give an advice.