# Rails Kaminari Pagination using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs, kaminari

I'm having troubles paginating using Ajax. My View code looks for pagination looks like

```
= paginate @products, :remote => true
```

However, the AJAX call fails with error status code and Web Inspector shows it as seen below
[image]

The server logs show

```
ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `eof?'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `run'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

What is interesting though is if I add a hyperlink to the same page like

```
= link_to('Test', products_path(:page => 2), :remote => true)
```

The link look exactly like the one generated by Kaminari and the Ajax call succeeds without any issues whatsoever. More interesting, if I change generated pagination link from

```
<a href="/brands/deborah-lippmann" data-remote="true" rel="prev">1</a>
```

to

```
<a href="/brands/deborah-lippmann" data-remote="true">1</a>
```

which has nothing to do with AJAX, the link works fine again.

Is it something to do with jquery-ujs magic happening before links are rendered by Kaminari which uses ActionView Extensions and ActionView Context to generate tags for pagination links? Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the javascript error you are getting?  It's showing `undefined` on line 7951 of `application.js`... If no request is being received by the server, then it must be a javascript issue.

Comment: There was no javascript error in console. The line 7951 of application.js is actually thick of jquery which 'creates transport if the browser can provide an xhr' and the actual code is
https://gist.github.com/dc87f34e1523a511fae7

Comment: Is that all that's contained in the server log?  Can you see what request was made that led to the error?

Comment: do you have <%= csrf_meta_tags %> in your layout ?
see this http://www.slideshare.net/adamlogic/jquery-and-rails-sitting-in-a-tree

Comment: maybe this can help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134028/jquery-rails-breaks-kaminari

Answer (score 0):

Chek /`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` for next lines

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```